# Will it be possible to use Java 8 on Glassfish 3?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

We currently use Glassfish 3 and I really want to use Java 8.  I tried upgrading to Glassfish 4, but I experienced two bugs in the Glassfish 4 code so I had to revert back to Glassfish 3.  Will Glassfish 3 work with Java 8 or will I have to upgrade my application container?

Comment: @Coffee what does that have to do with Glassfish **3**?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, it won't be possible (at the moment, maybe a workaround will occur later).

I tried Glassfish 3.1.1 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with the final Java 8 JDK which was released today. It doesn't even start the server, some OSGI exceptions are thrown.

As the comment to your question showed, it doesn't even work with earlier builds of Glassfish 4.0.

**Update 2015:**

It looks like there is a way to make it work with Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Open the file `/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/osgi.properties` of your Glassfish installation and add the following line at the end of the file: `jre-1.8=${jre-1.7}`

This should make the server start with JDK 8. It still doesn't work for Glassfish 3.1 or 3.1.1.

**See also:**

- [JDK-8020071 Unable to start Glassfish 3.1.1. with JDK 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8020071)
- [GLASSFISH-19363 GF fails to start on jdk8](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19363)

Comment: I got Glassfish 4 to work with Java 8 but you need to update glassfish with the update-tool and then start glassfish with a Java 8 vm. There seem to be some problems so don't use it in production environments!

Comment: Looks like the bugs you listed got resolved. Anybody knows if it's working now?

Comment: Actually, I've found osgi.properties in `/[GF-3.1.2HOME]/glassfish/config`.

Comment: I've modified `/[GF-3.1.2HOME]/glassfish/osgi/felix/conf/config.properties` file

Answer (score 40):

Stopped by an error after upgrading my Java 7 to Java 8.
Glassfish 3.1.2.2 just won't start.

Found a solution:

edit `osgi.properties` file in the `glassfish/config` folder and add this line at the end:

```
jre-1.8=${jre-1.7}
```

Comment: So glassfish starts up and your app works correctly after this minor change?

Comment: This change does allow GF3 to start. Does anyone have any experience beyond this to say if this is the only change needed?

Comment: just had a quick test with some sample apps, got on deployment gf is logging Exception while visiting xxxx.class of size 11939
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28954 on of the apps (ear) while one other war file seems ok... might be some config or import conflict... dunno if anyone has tried with more detailed tests?

Comment: Yup, this hack worked for me. (Win 7, GF Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2,
JRE: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 25.40-b25). Thanks! (My webapp is still built with Java 6, though).

Comment: This solution indeed makes glassfish start.... BUT: when I deploy a java 8 war, the app is deployed, but any classes that contain java 8 references are not loaded with a "Exception while visiting xxxx.class of size..." error

Comment: @Vova For the application to point to jdk 8, the path has to be changed in the admin config page of glassfish server. 
```
Configuration-> Server config - > JVM Settings-> JAVA_HOME
````

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the `osgi.properties` as mentioned in the other answer, the HTTPS listeners will not work anymore until a patch is applied as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74695287/4664606).