# Glassfish 3.1 returns an error when started Unable to start server due following issues: Launch process failed with exit code 1

Tags: glassfish

This is the trace :

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform ERROR: Error parsing system
>   bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework; version=1.6.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring;
>   version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2.0,
>   org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url;
>   version=1.0.0, org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.0, ,
>   org.glassfish.embeddable;org.glassfish.embeddable.spi;version=3.1.1
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be
>   zero length.) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package
>   names cannot be zero length.  at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:729)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.(ManifestParser.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.(ExtensionManager.java:220)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.(Felix.java:374)  at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher.launchOSGiFrameWork(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:77)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:128)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
>   ott 26, 2014 9:59:35 PM BundleProvisioner install

Please help me to solve why Glasfissh 3.1 does not start.

Answer (score 26):

I guess you have installed Java 8 but GlassFish 3.1 doesn't work with Java 8.

If this is the case you either have to install Java 6 or 7 or upgrade to GlassFish 4.

**See also:**

- [Will it be possible to use Java 8 on Glassfish 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462936/will-it-be-possible-to-use-java-8-on-glassfish-3)
- [JDK-8020071 Unable to start Glassfish 3.1.1. with JDK 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8020071)
- [Not able to start DAS with JDK8](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19263)

Comment: Yes. It is right! I disinstalled java 8 and installed java 7 and Glassfish 3.1 started (but now Glassfish 4. does not start).

Comment: I guess Glassfish 4 can't find your Java 7 installation but you should start a new question because this question here is related to Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why GlassFish 3 wasn't working with Java 8.