# GlassFish Tools in Eclipse with GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and Java 8

Tags: eclipse, java-8, glassfish, glassfish-3

Is it possible to configure GlassFish 3.1.2.2 to work with Java 8 in Eclipse plugin GlassFish Tools?
While creating server I need to choose GlassFish directory and Java directory and while choosing JDK 8 I get a message saying that I need Java 6 or 7 and 'next' button is disabled. Is it possible to make it work?

I tried to add

```
jre-1.8=${jre-1.7}
```

in osgi.properties file in the glassfish/config but it didn't change anything.

It's this stage I can't pass through:

[image]

only the message says that I need Java 6 or 7 instead of message you can see in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'glassfish' folder inside 'C:/Glassfish'? If so, that's the folder your Server Root needs to point to.

Regarding your main problem, yes, it can be set up that way (GF 3.1.1.2 and Java 8). But since it needs a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22517955/2316433) (basically, the one you mention in your post) to make it work, and it's [not officially supported](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html), I wouldn't recommend it for production environments. Did you restart your environment after applying the osgi.properties hack? Also, from the comments for the linked answer, here is something you might need to consider:

> I got Glassfish 4 to work with Java 8 but you need to update glassfish with the update-tool and then start glassfish with a Java 8 vm.